# How to save Tensorflow model in S3 (as /output/model.tar.gz) when using Tensorflow Estimator in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-s3, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Keras model getting trained using an entry_point script and I am using the following pieces of code to store the model artifacts (in the entry_point script).

```py
parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
model_dir  = args.model_dir
---

tf.keras.models.save_model(
      model,
      os.path.join(model_dir, 'model/1'),
      overwrite=True,
      include_optimizer=True
     )
```

Ideally, the model_dir should be `opt/ml/model` and Sagemaker should automatically move the contents of this folder to S3 as `s3://<default_bucket>/<training_name>/output/model.tar.gz`

When I run the `estimator.fit({'training': training_input_path})`, the training is successful, but the Cloudwatch logs show the following:

```
2020-09-16 02:49:12,458 sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training WARNING  No model artifact is saved under the path /opt/ml/model. Your training job will not save any model files to S3.
```

Even then, **Sagemaker does store** my model artifacts, with the only difference being that instead of storing them in `s3://<default_bucket>/<training_name>/output/model.tar.gz`, they are now stored unzipped as `s3://<default_bucket>/<training_name>/model/model/1/saved_model.pb` along with the *variables and assets folder*. Because of this, `estimator.deploy()` call fails as it is unable to find the artifacts in the *output/* directory.

```
Sagemaker Python SDK - 2.6.0
```

Estimator code:

```py
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='autoencoder-model.py',
                       role=role,
                       instance_count=1,
                       instance_type='ml.m5.large',
                       framework_version="2.3.0",
                       py_version="py37",
                       debugger_hook_config=False,
                       hyperparameters={'epochs': 20},
                       source_dir='/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/model',
                       subnets=['subnet-1', 'subnet-2'],
                       security_group_ids=['sg-1', 'sg-1'])
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: hi @inderpartap Cheema , did you find answer for this, running into similar issue

Comment: Same issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

```
parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
```

**to:**

```
parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
```

will work for me.  The `parser.add_argument` converts hyphens to underscores, so you can reference `args.model_dir` still.

Sagemaker container will save the trained model in '**model-dir**' and then make a zip file from this directory and upload to '**s3 bucket**' of location '**model_dir**'.

'**model-dir**' is the location inside the container **/opt/ml/..**

'**model_dir**' is mapped with the '**output_path**' which we define in:

```
tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='autoencoder-model.py', role=role,output_path=output_path,.....)
```

Hope this will help to resolve the isssue.